# Sum of real roots of the equation $x^2 + 5|x| + 6 = 0$?

Tags: quadratics

Sum of real roots of the equation $x^2 + 5|x| +6 =  0$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You should try to explain what you've tried and why it failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** It $r$ is a solution then so is $-r$

Note: After seeing Ryan's answer, I realized that the solution set is empty. Thus, Ryan's answer is the correct answer.

Now if we are looking for solutions inside $\mathbb{C}$, my hint can be used to deduce that either the solution set is infinite (hence the sum is undefined) or the sum is zero

Comment: Sir, will you explain why so?

Comment: that means sum does not exist

Comment: @Akash, for what are you saying:"that means sum does not exixt "? I can't understand. Could you please be precise?

Comment: my text book says $x^2, 5|x| and 6 $ are positive so the equation does not have any real root, Therefor sum does not exist

Comment: Oh my god! It is really amazing!! Didn't think that way!

Comment: sir i am little confused by the statement of my text book can  you explain it to me

Comment: @Akash The correct answer is that the solution set of this equation is empty as noted by RyanReich. It is a common convention to define the sum of elements of an empty set to be zero, thus the sum is zero. When I answered the question, I somehow assumed the existence of solutions. Since if $r$ is a root, then so is its additive inverse. Hence the sum of roots can be shown to be zero, if the solution set were non-empty

Comment: @Akash, I think you don't understand your book's explanation. Note that for any real $x$, we have $x^2\geq0$ and $|x|\geq0$. Now, note that $x^2 + 5|x| +6 \geq6> 0$. So, for no real $x$ we have this equation. Hope now you can understand the book's explanation. By the way which book are you reading? Is it ML Khanna or else?

Comment: thanks got it. The book is written and provided by our coaching center FIITJEE

Answer (score 8):

Another hint: all the terms are non-negative, and the constant term is actually positive.

Comment: One should agree about what the sum of the empty set is. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$|x|=x\forall x\ge0$

$|x|=-x\forall x<0$

**Case 1** $x\ge 0$

$x^2+5x+6=(x+2)(x+3)=0\Rightarrow x=-2,-3$ but we already  assumed $x\ge 0$ so $(\Leftrightarrow)$

**Case 2** $x<0$
then the equation becomes according to the definition of $|x|$

$x^2-5x+6=(x-2)(x-3)=0\Rightarrow x=2,3$ again $(\Leftrightarrow)$

$(\Leftrightarrow)$ is the sign  of contradiction

Comment: Are you sure? My impression is that the stated equation has *no* solution in the real numbers.

Comment: Well It was just a hint to show that it has really no real root as I  defined $|x|$

Comment: @egreg  Then that would be full answer! not a hint :D

Comment: @Sade Just add that something else has to be done (I removed my previous comment).

Comment: @Sade, Please help me. We should check your hint by putting the value of $x$ back in the original equation, right?

Comment: @Sush Is it clear now?

Comment: @Sade, Many many thanks. Yours is the answer which is most useful for other such problems, too. (And that's why I upvoted.) Sorry for being late, I went for walk.

Comment: @Sush How was the walk? you are most welcome